# The men on board a hospital ship

Tags: prepositions

The sentence is:

> The men on board a hospital ship that had taken a direct hit hadn’t been so lucky, however.

This is from a book called *The Dover Café At War* by Ginny Bell.

Why is it: The men **on board** a hospital ship...and not: The men **on board on** a hospital ship?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The phrase "on board" is a preposition meaning "on" (in the context of a vehicle or vessel), so there's no need to use another preposition (and in fact it's not grammatical). From NOAD:

> on or onto (a ship, aircraft, train, or other vehicle):
>
> - they are among more than 200 Britons on board the ship
> - all nine fishermen on board the vessel were rescued.

Answer (score 2):

"On board the ship" (also "aboard the ship") is basically nautical jargon -- it's a set form that isn't really used anywhere else (though you may occasionally see it used metaphorically).

Which is to say, don't try to figure out the grammar of the phrase, because it originates from the 1600s or before, in a very specific context that's well known for failing to follow the grammar rules of its own time, let alone ours. (Nautical jargon in English borrows a lot of words and phrases from Dutch, often mispronounced or misinterpreted.) The language used around ships is often just its own thing and you have to simply accept that it is the way it is without any real explanation.